# tkinter syntax comprehension

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I'm new and slowly been trying to learn some of tkinter and I've found a few nice resources for basic projects but the explanations of the codes have been a bit lacking and I'm hoping someone can help me understand a bit of what I've scrapped together.

**full code**

```py
from tkinter import *

#Create window and give it title
root = Tk()
root.title('Tip Calculator - Charlie')

#define the window sizes
window_width = 600
window_height = 400
#get the screen size
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
#solve for center of screen based on window & screen Size
center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width/2)
center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height/2)
#implement the above to position window width/height
root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')


var = IntVar()
frame = LabelFrame(root,text = "Tip %")
frame.pack(pady=10)

r1 = Radiobutton(frame, text = 'no Tip', variable = var, value = 0)
r1.grid(column =0, row =1)
r2= Radiobutton(frame, text = '10 %', variable = var, value = 1)
r2.grid(column=0, row =2)
r3=Radiobutton(frame, text = '15 %', variable = var, value = 2)
r3.grid(column=1, row = 1)
r4= Radiobutton(frame, text = '20 %', variable = var, value =3)
r4.grid(column=1, row=2)
```

code in question

```py
var = IntVar()
frame = LabelFrame(root,text = "Tip %")
frame.pack(pady=10)

r1 = Radiobutton(frame, text = 'no Tip', variable = var, value = 0)
r1.grid(column =4, row =1)
r2= Radiobutton(frame, text = '%', variable = var, value = 1)
r2.grid(column=4, row =2)
```

So I understand to an extent r1 is a variable name for the "Radiobutton", text is set to what pops up beside the button.
The question is what does variable = var, value = 1
and the first 3 lines i'm at a loss why is a variable called var being created and what does setting it = IntVar() do?
Is frame a widget? I assume pack is another version of positioning (grid) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your follow up question I think this would help you for how to handle the next steps.

```
from tkinter import *

def get_value():
    tab = 50 # set to 50 but could get a value from entry if you want
   
    choice = var.get()
    print(choice) # print your choice for clarification
    ten_percent = tab * .1 # math for tip
    total = ten_percent + tab
    if choice == 1:
        print("Your total plus tip is:", total)
        print("Your tip amount was:", ten_percent)
    
#Create window and give it title
root = Tk()
root.title('Tip Calculator - Charlie')

#define the window sizes
window_width = 600
window_height = 400
#get the screen size
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
#solve for center of screen based on window & screen Size
center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width/2)
center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height/2)
#implement the above to position window width/height
root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')


var = IntVar()
frame = LabelFrame(root,text = "Tip %")
frame.pack(pady=10)

r1 = Radiobutton(frame, text = 'no Tip', variable = var, value = 0)
r1.grid(column =0, row =1)
r2= Radiobutton(frame, text = '10 %', variable = var, value = 1)
r2.grid(column=0, row =2)
r3=Radiobutton(frame, text = '15 %', variable = var, value = 2)
r3.grid(column=1, row = 1)
r4= Radiobutton(frame, text = '20 %', variable = var, value =3)
r4.grid(column=1, row=2)
button = Button(root, text="Check", command= get_value)
button.pack()
```

Comment: I'm curious is there a widget to create a rotatable wheel the user can spin "adjust" to the correct % 0-100%

Comment: I am not aware of a widget for something like a rotatable wheel.  However, there is a tkinter scale widget that you can set either horizontally or vertically with a range of values that the user can slide up/down or left/right to select a value and maybe that would work. Check this out. <https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_scale.htm>

Comment: After a bit more looking I didn't find any rotatable wheel either. I think im just going to keep it simple and add a entry widget where if the user decides to enter a specific non-radiobutton tip percentage they just manually type what they'd like to tip. I appreciate the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

`variable = var` means that when the radio button is selected, the `IntVar` in the `var` variable should be given the value of this radio button. And the `value` option specifies the value that should be used for each radio button.

So after you select the `no Tip` radio button, `var.get()` will be `0`. After you select the `%` button, `var.get()` will be `1`. That's how you find out which choice they made with the radio buttons.

Later in the code you can write:

```
if var.get() == 0:
    tip = 0
elif var.get() == 1:
    tip = 0.10 * total_price
elif var.get() == 2:
    tip = 0.15 * total_price
elif var.get() == 3:
    tip = 0.20 * total_price

price_with_tip = total_price + tip
```

`pack()` is a geometry manager, an alternative to `grid()` and `place()`. See this [tutorial](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-pack/)

Comment: so to confirm later in the code "don't currently have it that far" when I get to the math and add a box to take user input I will use var.get(1) it will add the "10%" with the total of the bill.  Obviously theirs more needed to get there but that's essentially what/how it would go?

Comment: I've update the answer to show how you use it.

Answer (score 0):

This page will give you a nice explanation [radio widget](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_radiobutton.htm)

Var is being used to establish an integer variabel as opposed to string variable. (IntVar() vs StringVar()). Read through the explanation in that documentation and let me know if it still doesn't make sense. As for you question on pack() its just a fast method that literally packs the widget in the center and top if you don't specify anything else.